# TFS 2015 Trigger Continuous Integration With Tag commits

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I've got TFS 2015 running with Git repos using the new (non-XAML) build process. Is there some way to trigger a specific build when a new **tag** is pushed to the Git repo? The filter seems to only accept branch names.

Answer (score 6):

**Update** Microsoft has responded that it should be possible using the following as as a trigger:

```
refs/tags/*
```

or:

```
refs/tags/<tagname>
```

But apparently it is not yet in the on-prem version of TFS.

---

**Old answer**

TFS 2015 Update 1 doesn't have the possibility to trigger a build when a new tag is pushed.
TFS 2015 Update 2 is released not long ago, but I don't know if that version support tags or not.

Since I couldn't find any uservoice issue, [I created one](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/13326927-trigger-build-when-pushing-tag-to-git)

Comment: Does not work in even in TFS2015u3. (I tried setting Trigger to CI and include `tags/*` explicitly).

Comment: @mbx I also get errors when using the tag.. appearantly I didn't test it correctly, or it is not on the on-prem version...

Comment: refs/tags/* works fine with on-prem TFS 2017 (update 1)

Comment: Hi all, I can confirm that reft/tags/* works fine on TFS 2017.1.